# Euclidean Division of two polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Need help with this

> Compute the euclidean division of $x^3 - x^2
>  + x + 1$ and $g = x^5 + x^2 - x - 1$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you trouble? Can you also say which way the division is going? (Are you trying to find $g/...$ or $.../g$?)

Comment: the question was not really clear but i believe we are trying to find g/

Comment: @T.Bongers i have tried doing straight long division but i keep getting something that seems off

Comment: Can you please update your post to include what you've tried, and explain why you think it's not correct?

Comment: @T.Bongers i got x^2 + x with remainder of -x^2-2x+1

Comment: Almost correct (one sign wrong).

Comment: You can check by calculating $(x^2+x)(x^3-x^2+x+1)+(-x^2-2x+1)$.

Comment: ... in fact even better, substitute some values of $x$ in the above calculation rather than multiplying out symbolically.

Comment: @RobertIsrael oh its -x^2-2x-1